# Load exception Error in FXML file preventing program from running

Tags: java, exception, load, driver, fxml

Im working on an application and when I try to run it I keep getting the following error:

```
   Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/x/IdeaProjects/management%20system/out/production/management%20system/login.fxml:11
```

Below is the application start method:

```
    public void start (Stage stage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Employee management system");
    stage.show(); //showing the window
}
```

and below is the fxml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
   *line 11 <AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="30.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Database status " />
      <TextField fx:id="username" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="125.0" />
      <Label layoutX="30.0" layoutY="99.0" text="Username" />
      <Label layoutX="30.0" layoutY="174.0" text="Password" />
      <PasswordField fx:id="password" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="200.0" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="combobox" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="268.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Manager/Employee" />
      <Button fx:id="Login" layoutX="61.0" layoutY="338.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Login" />
      <Label fx:id="dbstatus" layoutX="186.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Label" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Im assuming the error has something to do with my fxml file however after looking at the file, I cannot find what the possible cause may be and was wondering what the cause of the error is?

Comment: Updated to indicate line 11 within the code

Comment: Is class `Controller` in a package?

Comment: No it is not in a package

Comment: What is the name of the class containing the `start()` method that appears in your question?

Comment: @Abra name of the class is Login

Comment: @Abra I put my Login class and my login.fxml file in the same package and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to get rid of the fx:controller from the anchorpane